# Fluid grid with automatically adjusting number of columns

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm wondering whether the following is possible with CSS:

- grid of DIVs, in any number of columns, let's say N (which could be anywhere from 5 to 20, or more)
- grid should be fluid, that is every DIV contracts and expands as the browser width changes, so that the DIVs take 100% of the browser width
- under certain browser width, grid switches to a N-1 column layout, that is, loses one column, and DIVs again expand to fit the browser width
- process should repeat until the layout becomes single column based, again with the DIVs width being fluid

I't kind of a hard to put to words, but it should behave similarly to images in this [page](http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html), but it should go all the way down to one column, and not jump from three to six column layout instantly.

I know I could do it with Javascript, and as it's done in the above link, with @media queries (with a lot of manual fiddling with column widths), but I'm wondering is there a way to do this only in CSS, and let the browser do the work for me?

Thanks.

Comment: mediaqueries is the way to go here if you are looking for the css only solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Twitter Bootstrap Grid system? Or at least reviewing and adopting a similar system? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem with their 'responsive' grid css (or whatever they call it).

Here is an example of the grid system in action. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/yS78x/1/

It utilizes media queries, like you mention above... but it is already kinda done for you and IMO is one of the easier grid system to adopt.